# "She told me how lucky I am I get to do this", does omitting "that" here sound natural?

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

I was reading [this](https://facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=199152388701282&id=100058195654401) post on Facebook in which the writer says:

> But when she held her grandchildren to sleep, it gave her an emotional
> reminder of what it was like. How beautiful it felt. How special it
> was. [...] She told me **how lucky I am I get to do this** every single
> night. And **how fortunate I am I get to do so** for a little while
> longer.

The phrases in bold sound very strange to me.

Shouldn't we say:

> How lucky I am **that** I get to do this every night.
> How fortunate I am **that** I get to do so for a little while longer.

?
Is omitting *that* really optional here?

Comment: You are correct. Alternatively "How lucky I am to get to do this every night."  The original words could be made correct with suitable punctuation.

Comment: It's all weak and badly-written but, yes - in *very informal* writing you can leave out 'that', but it's better not to. The repeated "I am I get to do" is ugly. The punctuation is wrong and I've never heard of holding a child to sleep.  Facebook isn't the best place to learn English, Mohammad.

Comment: Alternatively, you could say *how lucky I am to get to do this every night.*

Comment: This is poor writing. The best thing you can learn from this is what not to do. Also, here are some other sources to avoid imitating: newspaper headlines, song lyrics, non-native friends, and news media in general (with the exception of opinion columnists).